# core-api requests don't include user after successful TokenAuthentication

Tags: django-rest-framework, core-api

I'm using `django-rest-framework` to define a REST API for Python Clients to use. Clients access the API with `coreapi`. I log all access to the server application with a middleware.

I want clients to authenticate via username and password. I then use these credentials to receive the token for the corresponding user from an `auth-token` endpoint and use this token for `coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication`. I then want coreapi to sent requests in the name of the user which credentials and token were provided, but the requests made with coreapi don't include a user.

I tried using `coreapi.auth.BasicAuthentication` and `coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication`. In both cases I was able to authenticate and receive the correct API Endpoints, but no user is set when logging the requests made by coreapi in my middlware.

### Client code

```py
client = coreapi.Client()
schema = client.get(schema_url)
```

At this point I receive the schema:

```
token-auth: {
   create(username, password)
}
```

I then use the `token-auth` endpoint to obtain the token for my user.

```
response = client.action(schema, ['token-auth', 'create'], params={'username': username, 'password': password})
auth = coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication(scheme='Token', token=response['token'])

client = coreapi.Client(auth=auth)
schema = self.client.get(schema_url)
```

The schema now looks complete.

```
token-auth: {
    create(username, password)
}
users: {
   list([page])
   recent_users()
   read(id)
}
# ...
```

### Middleware

My middleware creates Log objects for each received request and appends the user like this:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    logs_data['user'] = request.user
```

The middleware successfully logs all requests made by my Python coreapi Client and sets the fields accordingly. For example `'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'coreapi'` is included in the requests metadata. I expected `request.user` to be set to the user that was used to authenticate earlier, but all I receive are AnonymousUsers.

Is there a way to send authenticated requests with coreapi including the user?